# How to handle generic dataclasses in dataclasses-json?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses, marshmallow

I'm working on defining a schema for fetching data from an API using dataclasses-json, which is based on Marshmallow. A lot of lists in the schema are wrapped in a `nodes` field, like this:

```json
{
  "foo": {
    "nodes": [
      {
        "bar": "baz"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My schema code currently looks something like this:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json

T = TypeVar("T")


@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class NodesWrapper(Generic[T]):
    nodes: list[T]

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Bar:
    bar: str

@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class Foo:
    foo: NodesWrapper[Bar]
```

When I run some actual data downloaded from the API (to avoid spamming it while I'm testing), I get something like this back in the REPL:

```
>>> from helpers.api_schemas.foobar import Foo
>>> with open(r'helpers\api_schemas\foobar_test_data.json') as f:
...     data = Foo.from_json(f.read())
...
>>> data
Foo(foo={'nodes': [{'bar': 'baz'}]})
```

What's supposed to be an instance of `NodesWrapper` is instead a `dict`!
Confused, I checked if there was something wrong with the Marshmallow schema:

```
>>> Foo.schema()
C:\Users\M1N3R\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\dataclasses_json\mm.py:263: UserWarning: Unknown type helpers.api_schemas.foobar.NodesWrapper[helpers.api_schemas.foobar.Bar] at Foo.foo: helpers.api_schemas.foobar.NodesWrapper[helpers.api_schemas.foobar.Bar] It's advised to pass the correct marshmallow type to `mm_field`.
  warnings.warn(
<FooSchema(many=False)>
>>>
```

A-ha! It wants a Marshmallow field type. Question is: what Marshmallow type does it want/need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I know I'm answering my own question, but I have found a solution after an annoyingly long time, and I don't want any of you to find yourself stuck with the same predicament.

I have moved from dataclasses-json to pydantic for handling ser/de in my app (I was working on a full re-write anyway, and it seems pydantic is even faster), and while it does have the same issue, I found a workaround through my ~~non~~impeccable Google-fu: Instead of using the subscripted generic type in the field (as in `foo: NodesWrapper[Bar]`), I subclassed the generic field, and redefined the `nodes` field to be a list of the target type, like:

```py
class Foo:
    class BarNodes(NodesWrapper[Bar]):
        nodes: list[Bar]
    foo: BarNodes
```

A little VSCodium multi-cursor magic and testing later, all seems to work fine. There is no broken ser/de system in Ba Sing Se!